# Attaching Debugger to Slurm compute node using Debugpy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh, slurm

I'm trying to debug code running on a SLURM compute node. I'm using VS Code to connect to the head node where I develop my code. To debug I have first to allocate a node to get access to a GPU. I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64700090/14290795 but got an error saying "The terminal process "/home/user/bash" failed to launch with exit code 1.". I tried to see what the problem was but found nothing useful.
Further, I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389686/14290795 however I don't know the password to the compute node (it's not the same as the one for the head node).

What I'm currently exploring is to debug via debugpy and attach via VS code. In my code I use:

```
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(5678)
print("Listening", flush=True)
debugpy.wait_for_client()
```

and the following launch.json configuration:

```
{
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "gpu15",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": false
},
```

where gpu15 is the name of the compute node. This gives me a connection refused. Is that setup correct? I'm not really sure what hosts to put in the `listen` function call and the launch.json. Any idea or explanation about the process is highly appreciated!